# What could cause "CPU noise" when Intel SpeedStep is enabled in the BIOS power settings?

Tags: power-management, speedstep

Whenever I enable the "Intel Speedstep technology" in the BIOS power configuration, I can hear noise when operating the laptop. The noise is sometimes a clicking noise in idle-mode or a buzzing noise (similar to the noise when reading from a spinning disk) when doing low work tasks (scrolling, moving the cursor, ...). I don't know if the noise is present when doing high work tasks, as that turns on the CPU fan, which is otherwise off.

When turning off the Speedstep technology, the noise is far less pronounced, but still barely noticeable in a silent room.

I could find another report that links high pitched noise with intel CPU power configuration: http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/324507-31-high-pitch-noise#r5308173
Though, that report does not include any causes for the noise and presents only a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to pinpoint the exact cause for this by the limited information available. Similar questions list different causes of the buzzing noise:

- https://superuser.com/a/1082987/229402: Changing the power configuration will alter the voltage and current "profile". This voltage pattern could cause resonance by electromagnetic waves with other electrically conducting materials, causing sound noise in the same way a loudspeaker creates sound waves.
- https://superuser.com/a/904480/229402 and https://superuser.com/a/716753/229402 specifically mention a DC-to-DC converter or bad capacitors/chips as a possible cause.

Comment: Just collecting together links to other questions and answers doesn't really make for a constructive answer.